# PHP If variable equals

Tags: php, if-statement

I am trying to show some text depending upon what a `status` is set to in a db table.

See my code below:

```
$result=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM hr_recruitment_stages where vacancy_ref='$vacancyref' order by added_on DESC limit 0,1")or die('ERROR 315' );
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
$stage_name = $row ['stage_name'];

if($stage_name['stage_name'] == 'Shortlisting') { echo"Shortlisting"; } else { echo"Not Shortlisting"; } ?>
```

However this doesnt seem to be working properly as it is showing as `Not Shortlisting` even when `stage_name` equals Shortlisting.

Any ideas why?

Comment: What have you done to debug this? What is the value of `$result`? What is the value of `$row`? What is the value of `$stage_name`? What is the value of `$stage_name['stage_name']`? `print` and `print_r` are your friends.

Comment: **Warning**:  You are using [an **obsolete** database API](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12859942/19068) which has been **removed** entirely from the latest version of PHP. You should use a [modern replacement](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php).

Comment: How is this not working? Have you checked to see what's actually in `$row['stage_name']`? You might want to check `$stage_name == 'Shortlisting'`, too

Comment: The value of stage_name is Shortlisting, so it should show as `Shortlisting`

Comment: fetch_assoc() will return an associative array. Try that instead of mysql_fetch_array()

Comment: @user3092953 — No. Not what value *should* it be, what value is it actually? You need to inspect it (e.g. with `print_r`).

Comment: Are you _assuming_ it has that value, or have you _verified_ it?

Comment: Using `$stage_name['stage_name']` does not make sense. `$stage_name` should not be an array.

Comment: [**How do I get PHP Errors to display?**](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1053424/4577762)

Comment: @Radmation, actually, [mysql_fetch_array](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-array.php): _Fetch a result row as an associative array, a numeric array, or both_. _MYSQL_BOTH (default)_. It should work anyway...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its variable type mistake. Check your assigned variable, you assigned the Array Element not the entire array. so try like below.

```
<?php
  $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM hr_recruitment_stages where vacancy_ref='$vacancyref' order by added_on DESC limit 0,1") or die('ERROR 315' );
  $row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
  $stage_name = $row['stage_name'];

  if($stage_name == 'Shortlisting') { 
    echo"Shortlisting"; 
  } else {
    echo"Not Shortlisting";
  }
?>
```

Refer this Article for PHP Array understanding.
http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php